# SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher with Startup set to Manual is Running after Bootstrap

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, startup

I have on my Windows 10 PC an instance of SQL Server 2017 Developer edition

All the services Startups are set to Manual

Today I started the PC and found in the SQL Server Configuration Manager that the `SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher` was Running

I'd expect for it to be Stopped, since the startup mode is set to Manual.

Why? Is this a normal behavior I'm unaware of?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer by myself.

I share it in case it might be useful for someone else

The default Shutdown setting for Windows 10 is "Fast Startup", that means that part of the running system processes are Hibernated instead than shut-down. This way at startup they are loaded in memory in the state they where when the PC was shut-down.

So long to the "turn it off and on again" to be working as expected

[image: IT Crowd image]

"Fast startup" can be disabled in the settings

[image: fast load setting]